# Why duplicate src package exist in maven project created using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: maven

Please refer following link to view project explorer:
http://imageshack.com/a/img911/2175/bXBZbh.png

More Details:
Eclipse: Mars 
BuildId: 4.5.1.M20150904-0015
OS: Linux

Steps which i followed:
New -> maven project -> repo location (selected the location of my local repository ) -> maven-archetype-quickstart

Comment: There are two "src -> main -> java" & two "src  -> test -> java"

Answer (score 2):

I see no duplicate src package. You have one for the normal sourcecode (src/main/java) and one for the test source code (src/test/java).

If you refer to the (seemingly) double occurrence of the src folder: This is only the way Eclipse shows you the project structure.

The real structure is as following:

```
- src
  -> main
     -> java
  -> test
     -> java
```

Since only the java folders are configured as source folders (and displayed with their full path) in Eclipse and marked as source folders, all other folders are displayed as regular folders in Eclipse.

Comment: Hey dunni, i got your explanation... But the real problem it has two such structure, which means
#1 - src
  -> main
     -> java
  -> test
     -> java
#2 - src
  -> main
     -> java
  -> test
     -> java

Comment: Not according to your screenshot.